# Links dont open in new tab and after the script in run once it keeps refreshing on the same page

Tags: python, selenium

I've found this script that im using but for some reason when links come through from Discord it doesnt open them in new tab and get stuck on refreshing same page multiple times.

the links come in from Discord at which point the browser picks em up but above error keeps happening it if it works on first link. it will get stuck on refreshing loop.

```
import sys, time, asyncio, discord, re, os, datetime, json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
options = Options()

from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands

prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
    
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
dirString = "user-data-dir=" + dir_path + "\\Default"
options.add_argument(dirString)
exePath = dir_path+"\\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=exePath)

keywords = ['amazon']

settingsFile = open("settings.json",)
cardsList = []
channels = []
pricesMax = []
serverList = []

data = json.load(settingsFile)

for item in range(len(data['cardDetails'])):
    cardsList.append(data['cardDetails'][item]["card"])
    channels.append(int(data['cardDetails'][item]["channelID"]))
    pricesMax.append(int(data['cardDetails'][item]["priceLimit"]))
    serverList.append(data['cardDetails'][item]["server"])

euroMultiplier = data["euroMultiplier"]
token = data["discordToken"]
attempts = data["attempts"]

if data["headless"] == "True":
    options.add_argument("--headless")


client = Bot('adawd@@#^^')
client.remove_command('help')
amazonPhrases = ["Dispatched from and sold by Amazon"]

global start_count
start_count = 0

async def check_urls(urls):
    start_time = time.time()
    for url in urls:
        if any(x in url.lower() for x in keywords):
            if ("amazon" in url):
                driver.get(url)
                #driver.find_element_by_id(url).click()
                bought = False
                count = 0
                url = driver.current_url
                print(timeString() + " | TRY: " + driver.title[0:20] + " | ", end = "")
                while count != attempts:
                    try:
                        if count == attempts:
                            break
                        box = driver.find_element_by_class_name("a-box-group")
                        merchInfo = box.find_element_by_id("merchant-info").text
                        price = box.find_element_by_id("price_inside_buybox").text
                        if price[0] == "£":
                            price = float(price[1:len(price)])
                        else:
                            price = float(price[1:len(price)]) * euroMultiplier
                        if "Amazon US" in merchInfo:
                            break
                        else:
                            if any(phrase in merchInfo for phrase in amazonPhrases):
                                for i in range(len(cardsList)):
                                    if cardsList[i] in driver.find_element_by_id("centerCol").find_element_by_id("productTitle").text.lower():
                                        if price < pricesMax[i]:
                                            driver.find_element_by_id("buy-now-button").click()
                                            if "Amazon EU" in merchInfo:
                                                buyBox = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,'subtotals')))
                                                buyBox.find_element_by_class_name("a-button-inner").click()
                                                bought = True
                                                count = attempts
                                            else:
                                                frame = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,'turbo-checkout-iframe')))
                                                driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
                                                button = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,'turbo-checkout-pyo-button')))
                                                button.click()
                                                bought = True
                                                count = attempts
                    except:
                        driver.get(url)
                        count = count + 1
                        
                if bought == False:
                    print("FAILED: " + driver.title[0:20])
                else:
                    print("BOUGHT: " + driver.title[0:20] + " | " + "%s SECONDS" %str((time.time() - start_time))[0:4])
                    delay = 2
                    driver.close()

            
def timeString():
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global start_count

    if start_count == 0:
        print("Connected to Discord and checking for messages\n\n")
        start_count += 1
    else:
        if message.channel.id in channels:
            if message.embeds:
                for embed in message.embeds:
                    toembed = embed.to_dict()
                    if str(toembed['type']).lower() != 'link':
                        urls = re.findall("(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|\b(?:[a-z\d]+\.))(?:(?:[^\s()<>]+|\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\([^\s()<>]+\)))?\))+(?:\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\(?:[^\s()<>]+\)))?\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'.,<>?«»“”‘’]))?",toembed['title'])
                        if urls:
                            await check_urls(urls)
                        try:
                            urls2 = re.findall("(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|\b(?:[a-z\d]+\.))(?:(?:[^\s()<>]+|\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\([^\s()<>]+\)))?\))+(?:\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\(?:[^\s()<>]+\)))?\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'.,<>?«»“”‘’]))?",toembed['description'])
                            if urls2:
                                await check_urls(urls2)
                        except:
                            pass
                        try:
                            for field in toembed['fields']:
                                urls3 = re.findall("(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|\b(?:[a-z\d]+\.))(?:(?:[^\s()<>]+|\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\([^\s()<>]+\)))?\))+(?:\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\(?:[^\s()<>]+\)))?\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'.,<>?«»“”‘’]))?",str(field))
                                if urls3:
                                    await check_urls(urls3)
                        except:
                            pass
            if message.content != '':
                urls4 = re.findall("(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|\b(?:[a-z\d]+\.))(?:(?:[^\s()<>]+|\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\([^\s()<>]+\)))?\))+(?:\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\(?:[^\s()<>]+\)))?\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'.,<>?«»“”‘’]))?",message.content)
                if urls4:
                    await check_urls(urls4)



client.run(token,bot=False)
```

Comment: Add more information. Which row returns what error?

Comment: no errors, it just keeps refreshing the page, again and again. even after the purchase was successful